# I am writing a batch file to start doing automatic firmware check

Tags: batch-file

I writing a sample batch file to dump my system info and firmware version in "result.txt", if firmware version will upgrade form 11.500.11.13 to 11.500.12.13 
 or 11.500.15.13, and then, I need to check is follow that rule.
How can I edit below batch file ?

```
 @echo off
     >"info.txt" systeminfo.exe 
     >"log.txt"  netsh mbn show interfaces 
     >"result.txt" (
         findstr /l /i /c:"System Model:" /c:"OS Version" "info.txt"
         findstr /l /i /c:"Model" /c:"Firmware Version" "log.txt"
     )
 del/f "info.txt" "log.txt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't told us the format of the `Firmware Version` line or whether your version numbers include leading zeroes.

Assuming your version number is of the form

> xxxx firmware version 11.500.11.13

and your numbering scheme does not include leading zeroes, then

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q43404681.txt"
SET "filename2=%sourcedir%\q43404681_2.txt"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('FINDSTR /i /L /c:"Firmware Version" "%filename1%"') DO SET "firmware=%%a"

FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=." %%a IN ("%firmware:*Firmware Version=%") DO (
 FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1-4delims=." %%p IN ("%filename2%") DO (
  SET "newer="
  IF %%p gtr %%a SET "newer=Y"
  IF %%p equ %%a IF %%q gtr %%b SET "newer=Y"
  IF %%p equ %%a IF %%q equ %%b IF %%r gtr %%c SET "newer=Y"
  IF %%p equ %%a IF %%q equ %%b IF %%r equ %%c IF %%s gtr %%d SET "newer=Y"
  IF DEFINED newer ECHO Upgrade: %%p.%%q.%%r.%%s
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q43404681.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

I used a file named `q43404681_2.txt` containing this data for my testing (a list of available software versions)

```
11.500.11.10
11.500.11.13
11.500.11.15
11.500.12.7
11.500.12.13
11.500.15.9
11.500.15.13
11.511.1.1
12.100.6.22
```

Which showed this result:

> Upgrade: 11.500.11.15
>   Upgrade: 11.500.12.7
>   Upgrade: 11.500.12.13
>   Upgrade: 11.500.15.9
>   Upgrade: 11.500.15.13
>   Upgrade: 11.511.1.1
>   Upgrade: 12.100.6.22

Having isolated the `Firmware version` line in `firmware`, we can remove the string `firmware version` and any preceding characters using the `:*` substring operator. We then use `.` as a delimiter and select the 4 resultant tokens into `%%a`..`%%d`.

Exactly the same argument for the list of available options to `%%p`..`%%s`; then simply compare the version numbers using the hierarchy and the `xxx` if-operator characteristic of comparing all-numeric arguments nemerically instead of alphabetically. The variable `newer` is used as a flag which is cleared as each available version is read and set to a value (it doesn't matter what value) if a later version is detected by the `if` logic`.

The `if defined` instruction operates on the run-time value of the variable so i `newer` has been set by any of the `if` commands, the upgrade line is reproduced.

---

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q43404681.txt"
SET "filename2=%sourcedir%\q43404681_2.txt"

REM ^^^^^^ These lines simply set up the filenames to be used

FOR %%a IN (osversion,systemmodel,biosversion,model,firmwareversion) DO SET "#%%a="

REM now we have cleared the variables to be used all of which begin "#"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('type "%filename1%"') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=: " %%p IN ("%%a") DO (
  IF "%%p%%q"=="OSVersion" SET "#osversion=%%r"
  IF "%%p%%q"=="SystemModel" SET "#systemmodel=%%r"
  IF "%%p%%q"=="BIOSVersion" SET "#biosversion=%%r"
  IF "%%p%%q"=="FirmwareVersion" SET "#firmwareversion=%%r"
  IF "%%p"=="Model" FOR /f "tokens=1,* delims=: " %%v IN ("%%a") DO SET "#model=%%w"
 )
)

SET #

REM This should have extracted the required data fields
REM The last "SET" is simply to display their values and can be deleted

REM You can now display whatever of these values you choose.

REM IF "filename2" contains a list of the possible firmware versions
REM available as in the list "11.500.11.10" to "12.100.6.22"
REM then this following routine should show all available versions
REM which are newer than the version installed according to your report


FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=." %%a IN ("%#firmwareversion%") DO (
 FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1-4delims=." %%p IN ("%filename2%") DO (
  SET "newer="
  IF %%p gtr %%a SET "newer=Y"
  IF %%p equ %%a IF %%q gtr %%b SET "newer=Y"
  IF %%p equ %%a IF %%q equ %%b IF %%r gtr %%c SET "newer=Y"
  IF %%p equ %%a IF %%q equ %%b IF %%r equ %%c IF %%s gtr %%d SET "newer=Y"
  IF DEFINED newer ECHO Upgrade: %%p.%%q.%%r.%%s
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Perhaps you should use google translate to convert the remarks in the above program to your language. The first block for instance translates to

IF "filename2"には、使用可能なファームウェアのバージョンのリストが含まれています
リスト「11.500.11.10」から「12.100.6.22」のように利用可能
この次のルーチンは利用可能なすべてのバージョンを表示する必要があります
あなたのレポートに従ってインストールされたバージョンより新しい

or

IF“filename2”包含可能的固件版本列表
可用于“11.500.11.10”至“12.100.6.22”
那么以下例程应显示所有可用的版本
它们比根据您的报告安装的版本更新

(sorry - It looks like Chinese to me - I can't tell the difference)

Comment: I'm sorry - that response makes no sense :(

Comment: @Magoo The first translated text is in Japanese, while the second one is in Chinese(simplified)...

Comment: @Magoo Thanks your help, but from the result, It's not include firmware, just export some upgrade information of OS/system/BIOS.